# Calculator Tkinter

Tags: tkinter, calculator

It'll be a simple calculator, but I'd like to make a "0" button which takes 2 columns ( 0 and 1). What should I do? I've tried something whith colmunspan but It does not work...
I don't want to use an "empty button".

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from Tkinter import Tk, W, E
from ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Entry, Style
#=========================================================================#

class Calc(Frame):

    def __init__(self,main):

        Frame.__init__(self, main)   
        self.main = main
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):        

        self.main.title('Calculator by MM')
        Style().configure("TButton", padding= (0,5,0,5), background = 'black',foreground = 'blue')

        self.rowconfigure(0, pad = 3)
        self.rowconfigure(1, pad = 3)
        self.rowconfigure(2, pad = 3)
        self.rowconfigure(3, pad = 3)
        self.rowconfigure(4, pad = 3)

        self.columnconfigure(0,pad =3)
        self.columnconfigure(1,pad =3)
        self.columnconfigure(2,pad =3)
        self.columnconfigure(3,pad =3)

        e = Entry(self,justify = 'right')
        e.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky = E + W)

        cof = Button(self, text = 'Back')
        cof.grid(row = 1,column = 0)
        clr = Button(self, text = 'C')
        clr.grid(row = 1,column = 1)
        neg = Button(self, text = '±')
        neg.grid(row = 1,column = 2)
        proc = Button(self, text = '%')
        proc.grid(row = 1,column = 3)
        pierw = Button(self, text = '√')
        pierw.grid(row = 1, column = 4)

        sied = Button(self,text = '7')
        sied.grid(row = 2,column = 0)
        os = Button(self,text = '8')
        os.grid(row = 2,column =1)
        dziew = Button(self,text = '9')
        dziew.grid(row = 2, column =2)
        dziel = Button(self,text = '/')
        dziel.grid(row = 2,column = 3)
        kw = Button(self, text = 'x^2')
        kw.grid(row = 2,column = 4)

        czt = Button(self,text = '4')
        czt.grid(row = 3,column = 0)
        pie = Button(self,text = '5')
        pie.grid(row = 3,column = 1)
        sze = Button(self,text = '6')
        sze.grid(row = 3,column = 2)

        jed = Button(self, text = '1')
        jed.grid(row = 4,column = 0)
        dwa = Button(self,text = '2')
        dwa.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        trzy = Button(self, text = '3')
        trzy.grid(row = 4,column =2)

        zer = Button(self,text = '0')
        zer.grid(row = 5,column = 1)

        krop = Button(self,text = '.')
        krop.grid(row = 5,column = 2 )


        self.pack()

    def run(self):
        self.main.mainloop()



Calc(Tk()).run()
```

Comment: what do you mean by "it does not work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the grid geometry manager, use the `columnspan` attribute to have a widget span multiple columns.

In your code, use grid on the zero button like this:

```
zer.grid(row = 5,column = 0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
```

That it telling it to go in column zero, span two columns (thus, columns zero and one), and stick to the edges of the space allotted to it.